# Musical Note Duration

Tags: c#, c++, signal-processing, fft

I implemented an FFT algorithm to find notes from guitar in real time. But now I want to see note duration. So on a tempo like 60 BPM (= 1 beat /second, 4/4 measure), I want to figure out if I played a quarter note or 2 eighth notes or 4 sixteenth notes.

Let's say that I can't play faster than sixteenth notes, so my FFT window will be on 250 ms.

Now if I hit note C (quarter note), I will get `C C C C`, if I hit 4 times note C (sixteenth note), I will also get `C C C C`.

How can I figure out if it's one quarter or 4 sixteenth notes?

I tried with volume on each window, but no luck. Any Ideas?

Comment: FFT sees freequency. You need to see amplitude (if the amplitude goes up and down within the window, it is a single note, if it continues into the next window, you need to track how many windows the note continues for).

Comment: How can I check if it continues into the next window?Amplitude should be smaller than a thrashold in this window?

Comment: Find the highest amplitude, and then see how far it goes until it reaches some level lower than that (probably less than 25%, but you probably need to experiment to find the right trigger level). It's a fairly trivial calculation (as long as it's just one tone at a time - if you have multiple tones, there's a fair bit more effort involved filtering out which tone is which, first). In other words, chords will be much more difficult to analyze.

Comment: To see if the note goes on, you can compare the total energy in two neighbouring windows. But you should really choose them to be substantially _smaller_ than the fastest expected note repetition. — Note that FFT on it's own isn't much good for determining the frequency of harmonic-rich signals such as guitar, you may want to try something based on [autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will try to analyze amplitude for now. I will check for multiple chords later. @leftaroundabout I don't see any problem in recognition with FFT until now, maybe on chords

Comment: You can use FFT to determine if a note is being played, like you said.  To find the beginning of the note you should look for a rising edge in the time domain.

Comment: This is hard problem, often called "audio segmentation". cf http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~paiemeje/references/to_read/music/beat/FXPAL-PR-00-094.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look for the 'attack' part of the sound, being this the amplitude peak.

By measuring the time between those peaks, you could find the duration of the note. This could not detect the slides and bendings, but it could wolrk for pick or finger strokes.